# GraphQL equivalent Join Query amoung collections?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, realm, graphiql

I am very new to Graphql. I have a basic question I want to write a GraphiQL query to fetch data among two collections I have a two collections one is Users and other one is Tasks.

Ideally in Sql the same would be written as follows…

SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Tasks ON Users.id = Tasks.user_id

I tried writing in GraphiQl. I also tried adding filters also tried adding relationships. But I always am not able to retrieve the data.

```
{
     users {
                _id
                tasks {
                         _id
                      }
          }
}
```

My collections are as follows. Please let me know if any more info is needed from me?.. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: I don't know which SDK you're using but I would suggest creating two way relationship. Your task is already aware of it's user so add a property to the user to be aware of the task. That's a 1-1 relationship (forward and inverse) but I would guess users will have multiple tasks, so add a List property to the user to store all the tasks and a LinkingObjects property to Tasks back to user(s). That provides a many-many relationship in both directions; when a task is added to a Users Task List, the inverse is automatically generated. In the future, please include objects as text in the question.

Comment: Using Realm .. and Apollo in Reactjs.... The relationship technique worked but it seems it broke some functionality as well in our other Apps using Realm sync... I am not sure how to use resolvers in GraphQL Realm.

Comment: Relationships are part of the core of Realm and should not break any functionality - obviously we don't know this specific use case but they are just part of the Realm world. I am not sure this question is answerable as-is. Perhaps writing some code and attempting to craft those relationships and then posting where you're stuck would help clarify the question.